# Unable to load entire data set from CSV file

Tags: matlab, csv

I'm unable to load an entire data set from CSV in Matlab. I'm new to Matlab so if the solution is trivial I apologize in advance.

The CSV is of dimension [2885 x 7].

I'm using `data = importdata(filename, ',');` which, according to the documentation is the correct usage.

However, the result of `data` of size [1332 x 7].

I've checked the CSV and there are no anomalies. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your CSV file have any non-numeric data? Have you tried `csvread` to see if that works better?

Comment: No non-numeric data, but I'll try `csvread` right now and see if that works better.